# Load dynamic data from the jquery.endless-scroll plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have the following code in the `<body>` of my view which does work however how do I load dynamic data from `loadmore.php`? I would also like it to not loop and stop at the bottom of the page?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
    {
        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
        $.ajax({
        url: "loadmore.php",
        success: function(html)
        {
            if(html)
            {
                $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
            }else
            {
            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
        }
    }
    });
    }
});
</script>
```

My loadmore.php code:

```
<html>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 bg-success">
        <h4><strong>My Title   |</strong><small> my mini title</small></h4>
          <h5>
{{$user->name}}
{{$user->username}}
{{$user->description}}
    </h5>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Big no no! you should make ajax requests to your controllers, not single php files

Comment: of course!! I should have known. Thanks